# How to add element which are not visible or not rendered in the pdf created using jspdf (along with html2canvas)

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf-generation, jspdf, html2canvas

Suppose I have two elements that are conditionally rendered depending on the route. But while creating pdf document I want to add both the elements in different pages with common header for both the pages.

I tried changing the route and then add the images of the captured page in the pdf doc. But this causes a flicker on the screen with additional task to keep track of current status of the pages.

Parent Component

```
     <div id="print-container">
            <h2>Document Header</h2>
            <div class="tabs-wrapper">
                <a class="tabs" routerLink="/one">
                    First
                </a>
                <a class="tabs" routerLink="/two">
                    Second
                </a>
            </div>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

First Component

```
<span> Displaying First </span>
```

Second Component

```
<span> Displaying Second </span>
```

Angular code in Parent

```
    let pdf = jsPDF({
      orientation: "landscape", 
      format: "a3"
    });
    let currentRoute = this.router.url;
    let container = document.getElementById("print-container");
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/one");
    await html2canvas(container).then(canvas => {
      let imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
      pdf.addImage(imgData, 0, 0);
      pdf.addPage();
    });
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/two");
    await html2canvas(container).then(canvas => {
      let imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
      pdf.addImage(imgData, 0, 0);
    });

    this.router.navigateByUrl(currentRoute);
    pdf.save("DOC");
```

I expect to create pdf as

```
Document Header
Displaying First

Document Header
Displaying Second
```

Comment: Can you precise what is actually your question? Note that a flicker is perfectly acceptable for the user when you send to printing/save a pdf IMO

Comment: @Kaddath Here flicker is that we first we change the route to first and then second. Then create pdf. After that we switch back to the routing url that we had before creating a print. So, if we are route "/two", then text changes from "Displaying Second" to "Displaying One" (switch to route '/one') to Displaying Two (switch to route 'two').     Here as its just the text change we wont notice major flicker. But when filled with lots of elements, the flicker will be too much evident and wont be good user experience.